# I am trying to addLiquidity on Uniswap v2 but I am getting error Reason provided by the contract: "TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED"

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereumjs, uniswap, nodes

```
 function addLiquidity(
    address tokenA,
    address tokenB,
    uint amountADesired,
    uint amountBDesired,
    uint amountAMin,
    uint amountBMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity) {
    (amountA, amountB) = _addLiquidity(tokenA, tokenB, amountADesired, amountBDesired, amountAMin, amountBMin);
    address pair = UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
    TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenA, msg.sender, pair, amountA);
    TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenB, msg.sender, pair, amountB);
    liquidity = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).mint(to);
}
```

- I have minted 2 ERC Token say Token1 & Token2 and also approved the address of deployed Router v2 contract from Token contracts.
- Also generated the INIT_CODE_HASH in the factory contract and added to the hash value by removing 0X.
- While trying to transact addLiquidity function I am getting an error "TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED".

I have used the deployed code of Router & Factory contracts from ether scan. I am unable to point out the issue any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you been approving your contract in both token1 and token2 contract (ie spender=your contract, token owner=msg.sender and value=amountA or B, accordingly) ?

Comment: Agree with DrGorilla, without knowing more, I think the two ERC20 tokens you deployed can't be moved by the contract that's implementing addLiquidity.

You may need to do: `tokenA.approve(ContractCallingSafeTrasnfer, AmountUsuallyMAXINT)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UniswapV2Pair needs to be deployed as well for addLiquidity to work.
Use remix editor to deploy the contract and call addLiquidity from remix. If transaction still fails remix debugging tool can be used to track the code flow step by step

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).